# C# Convert DateTime value from one timezone to another

Tags: c#, date, datetime, timezone

I am storing DateTime values in db with the time zone "Turkey Standard Time" and i need to show these dates with user's timezone settings.

For example if user timezone setting is: "Hawaiian Standard Time" then i want to convert datetime value stored in db from Turkey Standard Time to Hawaiian Standard Time

And i also need to opposite conversion converting time for example from Paraguay Standard Time to Turkey Standard Time

Is there a method or and extension method for DateTime for converting time between two timezones? Result method should look like this:

```
var date = ConvertDateTime(DateTime date, TimeZoneInfo from, TimeZoneInfo to);
```

Comment: The static `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` method has exactly the signature you've specified.

Comment: (As an aside, if you can avoid storing everything in the database in the Turkey time zone, that would help. In many cases it's best to store everything in UTC; in other cases (e.g. event scheduling) it's best to store them in "the time zone of the event" (with a field specifying what that time zone is).

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you i didnt know that method. It works as i needed. And thank you for the suggestion, i will keep that in my mind.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting the question at this point. Anyone who finds it via search is likely to find the method with the same search - a Google search for your exact title gives the `ConvertTime` documentation as the second result, after this question as the first one.